# Only display a specific part of a WebKitWebView in swift

Tags: swift, webview, scrollview, wkwebview

It`s probably a very easy question but I'm new at coding.

In my app I display the normal Webpage of Wikipedia in a `WebKitWebView`.
I want to display the whole page but without for example the last 100px. Is there a way to "cut off" the content of a `Webview` respectively a scrollview. For some reason

```
print(webView.scrollView.contentSize.height)
```

is 0.0.

I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can try when the webView finishes the load

```
webView.scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: webView.scrollView.contentSize.width, height: webView.scrollView.contentSize.height - 100)
```

Comment: That‘s exactly what I‘ve tryed.

Comment: In webview did finish navigation. But now I tried: webView.scrollView.contentInset.bottom = -250

But this causes that every section in the article is expanded....